# How to find minimum possible projection of a polygon on X axis, after rotating at an arbitrary angle?

Tags: c++, algorithm, rotation, geometry, computational-geometry

Given the vertices of a 2D polygon, I have to find the minimum possible projection of the polygon on `X` axis.

I am allowed to rotate the polygon at arbitrary angle.

At first I thought for the minimum case, at least one of the polygon's sides will be aligned to the `X` axis, which is not true.

The polygon can be concave or convex.

Comment: Please be clearer. "The minimum projection of a polygon" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Intuition tells me that at least one *pair of vertices* will be aligned to the X axis Could be wrong of course.

Comment: This rotation is done with respect to what point? The center of mass of the polygon? The center of the Cartesian system? Any point that belongs to the polygon?

Comment: @John yes, my intuition also tells me so. But I need a solid proof.

Comment: A trapezoid with height less then the width won't have a pair of vertices aligned to X axis.

Comment: @justhalf Yep, my intuition was hopeless.

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems the question is pretty clear to quite a number of people.

Comment: I think the correct intuition should be "at least one side (after making the concave polygons into convex) should be perpendicular to X-axis"

Comment: I suspect that OP's *minimum possible projection* is the same as the minimum width of the polygon. If the polygon is convex then I suspect *rotating calipers* would help.  If the polygon is non-convex then I suspect that its convex hull has the same minimum possible projection.

Comment: @High Performance Mar, Most probably rotating calipers doesn't work. As that method assumes any of the polygon's sides will be aligned to `X` axis. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not an answer, but a simplification: You need to look at convex polygons only. Because any vertex that has an inner angle > 180° between the previous and next vertex (that means, an "indentation") can never be one of the outer vertices in any projection. You can skip them and construct a convex polygon from the remaining "outer" vertices.

Comment: @BidhanRoy: you are wrong.  Rotating calipers do not depend on axis-alignment of any of the edges of the polygon.  But if they did one could first rotate the polygon so that one of its edges is axis-aligned, this won't affect the minimum width of the polygon.

Comment: The assumption hat one of the edges is aligned to the x axis is clearly incorrect. Assume a "flat" triangle with 10°, 10° and 160°. If you align any edge with the x axis, the projection on the y axis is smaller than projection on x axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, the answer will not chnage if you replace the polygon with its convex hull. So let' s think polygon is already convex. Now assume we found the minimal angle. It means we have a strip parallel to Y bounding the body. Easy to see that one of polygon sides can lie on the strip boundary (if it is not, we can rotate the body slightly without increasing the strip width).

Summarizing, we get an algorithm: compute the convex hull, then for each side of the hull select an angle which makes it parallel to Y and test the width. Take the min.
0

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is called the "Rotating Calipers Algorithm".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers

The Wikipedia page about this algorithm has even pseudo-code for your problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers#Minimum_width_of_a_convex_polygon

Answer (score 0):

Let X(i, alpha) be the X-coodrinate of vertex i after rotation by angle alpha.

We always assume -PI <= alpha <= PI .

Let i=rightmost(alpha) if X(i, alpha)>=X(j, alpha) for all j. Let i=second_rightmost(alpha) if X(i, alpha)>=X(j,alpha) for all j except one.  Similarly define leftmost() and second_leftmost().

Let us prove the following: if X(i, alpha) >= X(j, alpha), and X(i, beta) >= X(j, beta), and beta-alpha < PI, then X(i, gamma) >= X(j, gamma) for all gamma in [alpha, beta].  Indeed, X(i, alpha)=x[i]*cos(alpha)-y[i] * sin(alpha), where (x[i], y[i]) are initial position of the vertex i. Therefore, X(i, a) - X(j, a) = c1*cos(a)-c2*sin(a), where c1=x[i]-x[j],c2=y[i]-y[j]. Let f(a)=X(i,a)-Y(i,a). The function f is continuous, and changes its sign when tan(a)=c1/c2, that is, a=atan2(c1,c2)+PI*n. If beta-alpha

Now we have:

- if rightmost(alpha)=rightmost(beta) and beta-alpha < PI, then rightmost(x)=rightmost(alpha) for all alpha < x < beta.
- if i=rightmost(alpha)=second_rightmost(beta), and j=rightmost(beta)=second_rightmost(alpha), and beta-alpha < PI, then for all x between alpha and beta, rightnost(x) is either i or j, and the point of change is atan2(y[i]-y[j], x[i]-x[j]).

This is enough to obtain with binary search at which interval which point is the rightmost.  By sign inversion of angles, we get the leftmost point intervals.  Since we know at which interval each point is leftmost, and each is rightmost, we can calculate the values at the borders between intervals, and select the minimal one.